# Background Audio Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-phone-8.1, background-audio

I have built an cross-platform app that involves playing audio (podcast mp3 files) in the background.

I have followed the examples as best as I can for performing background audio on Windows Phone 8.1 XAML apps.  It will launch and try to start sometimes giving a second or two of audio, and then I get this in the output:

```
The program '[3284] Windows.Media.BackgroundPlayback.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

I don't even know where to look from here.  It doesn't seem to raise an actual exception in the application itself.  Any idea what is wrong or how to further troubleshoot this?

Comment: It's hard to say anything based on this much info. Attach an event handler to the `taskInstance.Canceled` event of your audio task and print the `BackgroundTaskCancellationReason` to get a better idea.

Comment: @Ali250 In my case it crashes with code 0. I tried what you suggested, but it never gets to the event handler.

Comment: Does it even enter the `Run` function of your background task at all? Did you go through the usual checklist for background tasks i.e. adding capability in appxmanifest, adding a reference to the runtime component in your main project etc? Also, are you getting a deferral for the task?

Comment: No, it wasn't going to Run task at all.  I went through troubleshooting guides and realized I had the library set to "Class Library" instead of "Windows Runtime Component".  First time writing a background task, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these items:

1. You passed full class name into the *Package.appxmanifest* (see [here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/) example)
2. You referenced task project from main project ([download](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) Microsoft example and try to copy project references idea)
3. Both projects have the same Windows Phone version (e.g. 8.1, 10, etc.)
4. The Task project has output type *Windows Runtime Component* (not *Class Library*)
5. And of course: try to remove all files except Backround Task and repeat items above again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was solved by uninstall installed app and deploy it again.